# Chef recipe to install VS code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, chef-infra

I need to update a existing Chef recipe to install VS code and its extension

Using below chef-recipe i am able to install VS code (code-server)

```
rpm_package 'code-server' do
   source "code-server.3.10.xx.rpm"
   action :install
end
```

Command to install code-server extension manually is

```
code-server --install-extention extension-name.vsi
```

I am not able to find any chef module to perfom this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource to run commands is the [execute resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/). You can run the `code-server` command from within this resource, like:

```rb
execute 'install code-server extension' do
  command 'code-server --install-extention extension-name.vsi'
end
```

You can set the path to the binary or current working directory (`cwd`) as required.